# Concrete Example of Quantum Entanglement, Quantum Steering and Bell Nonlocality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, non-locality

I was reading the wikipedia page for [quantum steering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_steering). The following is the mathematical way they have described the three notions:

[image]

Is there any concrete example of these three concepts? Like, any state assemblage and measurement assemblage that can differentiate among them? TIA

Comment: what do you mean with "state assemblage"? Also, did you have a look at the related paper by Wiseman et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0612147)?